# How to reference widget inside of a Service?

Tags: android

How to i i set the TextView and ProgressBar to their findViewById views from inside a service?>

```
 ProgressBar dialog;

TextView Titletext;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("StackWidgetService", "Inside of onCreate in Widget Service");

    getter fethcer = new getter();
    fethcer.execute();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get a reference to the [AppWidgetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html) and update the layout.

```
AppWidgetManager awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
int[] appWidgetIds = awm.getAppWidgetIds(yourProviderComponentName);
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.thelayout);
// Construct the remote views here ...

awm.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[0], rv);
```

This example only updates the layout of the first widget instance (`appWidgetIds[0]`) or probably even crashes if there is no widget. Usually you have to loop over the `appWidgetIds`-array and update each one individually; or skip the loop if no widget instance is present.